# Prove that all Markov Chain have a unique state of equilibrium.

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains

I have the following problem, for which i don't know how to start:

Prove that all Markov Chain have a unique state of equilibrium. That is, if $P$ is the transition matrix of a Markov regular chain, then there exist a unique vector $$v=(v_1,\cdots,v_n)$$ such that $v_i>0$, $\sum v_i=1$ and $Pv=v$.

Please if some one can helpme I would be grateful.

Comment: Not true for all Markov chains (consider the identity), but, yes, true for regular. You do see existence? Uniqueness is a bit trickier.

Comment: OK. But how can i prove th existence and the uniqueness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINTS**: Start by showing (using the definition of a Markov process) that $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. Then show that if all the entries of $A$ are positive, the  vector $(1,1,\dots,1)$ is the only eigenvector (up to scalar multiples) with eigenvalue of the matrix $A^\top$. (In general, you'll need to apply this to some power of $A$. Check the definition of regular.)

Comment: I Know that the eigenvalue $\lambda=1$ has multiplicity $1$ for $1-$regular matrix, and for $k-$regular matrix of any order. Also i know that if the matrix is $1-$regular it's entries are positive. Can you write your idea explicitly? Please.

Comment: Well, if you **know** that the eigenvalue $\lambda$ has multiplicity $1$ for a regular Markov process, you're done. I'm trying to get you to try to write a proof here, rather than just giving it to you. Surely the fact that the columns of $A$ each add up to $1$ should tell you that $1$ is an eigenvalue. Why? (One reason I want you to write ideas here is that I have no idea how much linear algebra you know. So show me!)

Comment: Thanks i tried what you say and in fact obtain the answer.

Comment: That's awesome. Keep up the good work.